# What does "yet for" mean in following sentence?

Tags: meaning

These facilities will have the lowest environmental impact yet for an Apple data centre.

Comment: It's not an idiom or phrase. *yet* means *until now*, *for* refers to *out of all [data centres]*

Comment: A rewrite is possible (though stylistically inferior): _These facilities will have, for an Apple data centre, the lowest environmental impact yet._

Comment: Based on an inadequate/ incorrect parsing of the sentence.

Comment: The *yet* tags on to *lowest* (lowest yet = lowest so far) -- the rest of the story you know.

Comment: In that sentence "yet for" does not constitute a semantic unit. The words are merely next to each other.

Comment: You just need to place a comma, or semi-colon, between *yet* and *for*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***These facilities will have the lowest environmental impact yet for an Apple data centre.***

***Yet*** is an adverb qualifying *the lowest environmental impact*.

It means *so far / up to this moment*